# How to submit a form from c#

Tags: c#

I am developing a internal app in c# which calls one of the banking site. I need to enter curency in DDL, amount in textbox and neeed to find out the exchange rate.

here is the link which i need to use..

https://www.timesofmoney.com/remittance/secure/rmtExchRateCalculator.jsp?tab=US&sendercountry=US&sendercurrency=USD&uiId=TOML&partnerId=TOML

I used myWebClient.UploadValues(C#) but the site is returning some errors...can some one help me with this..

### My Code:

```
    string uriString= "https://www.timesofmoney.com/remittance/secure/rmtExchRateCalculator.jsp?tab=US&sendercountry=US&sendercurrency=USD&uiId=TOML&partnerId=TOML";

    // Create a new WebClient instance.
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

    // Create a new NameValueCollection instance to hold some custom parameters to be posted to the URL.
    NameValueCollection myNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();



    // Add necessary parameter/value pairs to the name/value container.
    myNameValueCollection.Add("selCountry", "United States");
    myNameValueCollection.Add("rmtAmount", "100");

    byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadValues(uriString, myNameValueCollection);

    Response.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray));
```

---

The response I got from the site:

---

Inconvenience Regretted !

Please check your browser settings to enable you to use the site. You may be facing this problem due to old cookies and temporary internet files

Delete the temporary Internet files.

To delete the temporary Internet files, follow these steps: 
Start Internet Explorer. 
On the Tools menu, click Internet Options, and then click the General tab. 
Under Temporary Internet files, click Delete Cookies. 
Click OK when you are prompted to confirm the deletion. 
Click Delete Files. 
Click OK when you are prompted to confirm the deletion. 
Under History, click Clear History. 
Click Yes when you are prompted to delete your history of visited Web sites. 
Click OK. 
Close all open browsers and restart new browser again

---

Comment: It would help an awful lot if you'd say exactly what "some errors" means.

Comment: Which errors? Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the page requires cookies. Take a look [here](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html) to see how to handle cookies with WebClient.

To debug your problem you can also install a header sniffing tool like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/3829) for Firefox or [ieHTTPHeaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html) for Internet Explorer and try to send the same information via WebClient (same User Agent, [Referrer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer) etc.).

Comment: I'd also recommend Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) for helping with this sort of scraping work.

Comment: i tried with your code..but it is not working..i am getting the same response from that site.

Comment: Perhaps it's also requiring a special Referrer. Monitor the HTTP headers when you're accessing the page in the browser and make WebClient look like your browser by using the same headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try www.coinmill.com. I used javascript to get the exchange rate/currency conversions of there site with no problems. Hope this helps